# I am using the following code to get data from OpenAI API . When i hit the request on postman , it runs for a while and then shows socket hangup

Tags: node.js, json, api, openai-api

```
const PORT = 8000;
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors)

const API_KEY = "My API Key"



app.post('/completions' ,async(req,res)=>{

    const options = {
        methods:"POST",
        headers:{
            "Authorization":`Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
            "Content-type":"Application/json"
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
                model:"gpt-3.5-turbo",
                messages:[{role : 'user' , content:"how are you?"}],
                max_tokens:100,
        })
    }
    try{
        console.log("here")
        const response =  await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',options)
        const data = await response.json()
        res.send(data);
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})

app.listen(PORT,() =>console.log("Your Server is running at " + PORT))
```

It should show a response from the openAI API  if I hit a post request on my local server through Postman on http://localhost:8000/completions right?

Comment: Does `console.log("here")` print out `here`?

Comment: no . it does not .

Comment: Could you comment out `app.use(cors)` and try running again? Also update `methods` to `method` in the `options`.

Comment: It does work without CORS , but when i make a post request from the frontend it shows the following "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled." Also when i enable cors it gets stuck !!

Comment: then it's the problem with cors, not with openai api.

Comment: Then how do i make a call from frontend to the backend to fetch the data ?